# How to use c++ .lib(c++ static libraries) file in python

Tags: python, c++, wrapper

I have some .lib(c++ static library) files and I need to use them in my python program.

I know I should use wrapper but I don't know how and have no idea what is that. I searched and found that ctypes python library uses .dll to load the library and as I have .lib files I don't know how can I use them in python.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to write a [Python extension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html) based on your C++ code, but if that's too complicated, you can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html) but then your static library will need to be a shared library instead.

Keep in mind that for writing Python bindings you have several options, like [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [PyBind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), [Shiboken](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/shiboken2/index.html), etc.

Comment: how can i use static library as shared library?

Comment: @MohammadAli You will have to link the static library into a shared object (Posix platforms) or DLL (Windows).  You will need a linker for that.

Comment: How can I link static library into DLL? I couldn't find anything  @MartinBonner

Comment: @MohammadAli That's odd.  I found lots of hits when I googled "link static library into dll".  You will need to understand the difference between a dll and a static library, and how the tools work.  If you have no experience working with non-python code that's going to be a learning experience.  Comments are not the right forum to discuss this (and questions on SO are probably not either - you need the good book list.